# How to pass parameters to a Yii2 view from javascript file?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I have a js file through which I am making an ajax call to render a view file and pass some data. How can this be done? Here is my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "index.php?r=orders/on-select",
        data: {myVar: myVar},
        success: function (data) {
            //I want to render the view here and pass the data
        },
    });
```

Comment: explain better please  .. the ajax call is correct  .. you have problems server side?  ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes You can do it using ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "index.php?r=orders/on-select",
    data: {myVar: myVar},
    success: function (data) {
        //I want to render the view here and pass the data
    },
});
```

Now  in your controller render the view you want and echo it

```
    public function actionNoSelect(){
             if(isset($_REQUEST['myVar'])){
                $html = $this->renderPartial('path to your view file',[
               'model' => $model///// passing data to your view file if you want
],true)
echo $html;
}
    }
```

Now in your ajax success function you can show it in some div like

```
success: function (data) {
      $('#divid').html(data);
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Understand the concept first, ajax() and its working remains the same whether you are working on core Php or some Php framework.

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'your url',
    type: 'get'  // 'get' / 'post'
    data: {
        var1 : val1,
        var2 : val2,
        var3 : val3,
        // and so on
    }
});
```

You can pass as many parameter as required in key : value pair and get fetch its value in php like:

`$_POST['var1']` or `$_GET['var1']`